# Node.js POST request hangs forever in Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have managed to set up a registration system following a tutorial, and have been playing around trying to get my own data to POST my MongoDB, but the Postman request sends forever. I am not sure if I have missed something out or if I am using incorrect syntax?

I am just trying to post two strings for my ‘Hobby’ model.

hobbies.js (api) is included in routes/api.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Hobbies = require("../models/Hobby");

// @route   GET api/posts/test
// @desc    Tests post routes
// @access  Public - (Private routes are for registered and logged in users)
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Hobbies page Works" }));

router.post("/newhobby", (req, res) => {
  //else create the new user in the DB using the data input by user
  const newHobby = new Hobbies({
    newhobby: req.body.newhobby,
    classes: req.body.classes
  });
});

//make router available elsewhere (from server.js in this case)
module.exports = router;
```

Hobby.js (model) the model is defined in my routes/models folder

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create schemac
const HobbiesSchema = new Schema({
  newhobby: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  classes: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = Hobby = mongoose.model("hobbies", HobbiesSchema);
```

Server.js handles the config of my server

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const profile = require("./routes/api/profile");
const posts = require("./routes/api/posts");
const donate = require("./routes/api/donate");
const hobby = require("./routes/api/hobbies");

const app = express();

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB  config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to DB through mongoose
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

//Passport config
require("./config/passport.js")(passport);

// Use routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/profile", profile);
app.use("/api/posts", posts);
app.use("/api/donate", donate);
app.use("/api/hobbies", hobby);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server runnning on port", port));
```

Postman Stuck
[image: Postman Stuck POST request]

Comment: You don't do anything in `router.post("/newhobby"` you just create a new document, you will need to save it and then call `res.send/json` when you are done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this post route:

```
router.post("/newhobby", (req, res) => {
  //else create the new user in the DB using the data input by user
  const newHobby = new Hobbies({
    newhobby: req.body.newhobby,
    classes: req.body.classes
  });
});
```

You don't send any response back to the client/browser.   Thus, it sits there waiting for a response, but one never comes.  I don't know what you want the response to be, but for a programmatic request, it could just be something as simple as:

```
res.json({response: "ok"});
```

or

```
res.send("ok");
```

If this is a form posted from a browser, then you will want to send back an HTML page to be displayed after the form is submitted.

```
router.post("/newhobby", (req, res) => {
  //else create the new user in the DB using the data input by user
  const newHobby = new Hobbies({
    newhobby: req.body.newhobby,
    classes: req.body.classes
  });
  // do something here with newHobby

  // then send a response
  res.send("all done");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the Postman request now completes and returns 'all done', but nothing seems to be sent to the db. I'm unable to see the data in MongoDB I submitted through Postman.

Comment: @Gaz - You didn't save anything in the database yet.  You just created an object.  I don't know your database particularly well, but you probably need to do `newHobby.save()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do anything with the document, you will need to first save it and then send it to the client.

When an error occurs set the status to 500 and send 
an error message to the client

If you are unfamiliar with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), `.then` and .`catch` will confuse you, take the time to read the link about promises

```js
router.post("/newhobby", (req, res) => {
  const newHobby = new Hobbies({
    newhobby: req.body.newhobby,
    classes: req.body.classes
  })

  newHobby.save()
    .then(res.json)
    .catch(e => res.status(500).json({ message: e.message })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your db in your 'config/key' if the password are inside "<>" stances. Just remove them and try it.

```
"mongodb+srv://user:<password>@cluster..."
```

to

```
"mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster..."
```

Answer (score -3):

try downgrading the node.js version to 2.2.12 when configuring the connection string in an Atlas cluster, like so:

[image]